# Names list and store element in different categories in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, sublist

dataframe tidy2:
[image]

I'd like to convert the part of dataframe that satisfies my specific conditions into a list. For example, for all communities contain "BAYSHIRE", I want to store their facility number, name and licensee as the first element in a list and called this element "BAYSHIRE", for communities contain "EMERITUS" or "BROOKDALE", store their facility number name and licensee as the second element in a list.

```
key = list("BAYSHIRE", c("EMERITUS", "BROOKDALE"), "AGEMARK")
big_organization <- list()

for (i in 1:length(key)){
  org = tidy2 %>%
    filter(str_detect(Licensee, key[[i]]) | str_detect(Facility_name, key[[i]] )) %>%
    select(Facility_number, Facility_name, Licensee)

     
  big_organization = append(big_organization, or)
}
big_organization
```

Output for above code:
[image]

ck.imgur.com/88Ya3.png

**Expected output:**

$BAYSHIRE

Facility_number             Facility_name              Licensee

374604274  VISTA DEL LAGO MEMORY CARE   DEL DIOS CARE,LLC;BAYSHIRE, LLC
374604267   CLOISTERS OF THE VALLEY, LLC    DEL RIO CARE, LLC; BAYSHIRE, LLC
374603778   HERITAGE HILLS  HAWKES O-SIDE 1 LLC; BAYSHIRE LLC

$EMERITUS, BROOKDALE

Facility_number             Facility_name              Licensee

336413087   BROOKDALE MURRIETA  BLC CHANCELLOR-MURRIETA LH LLC
197606301   BROOKDALE MONROVIA  BLC GABLES-MONROVIA LP
197606676   BROOKDALE GARDENS OF TARZANA    BLC GARDENS-TARZANA, LP
496803339   BROOKDALE PAULIN CREEK  BLC LODGE AT PAULIN INC GP, BLC LODGE AT PAULIN LP
306002955   BROOKDALE NOHL RANCH    BLC NOHL RANCH LLC
198204758   BROOKDALE OCEAN HOUSE   BLC OCEAN HOUSE LP
374601046   BROOKDALE PLACE OF SAN MARCOS   BLC-BROOKDALE PLACE OF SAN MARCOS LP
306003639   BROOKDALE BREA  BREA BREA LLC; EMERITUS CORPORATION
347003712   BROOKDALE SYLVAN RANCH  BREA CITRUS HEIGHTS LLC; EMERITUS CORPORATION
197606945   BROOKDALE CENTRAL WHITTIER  BREA WHITTIER LLC; EMERITUS CORPORATION
.
.
.
.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you with an actual sample of your data. Please see [how to make great r reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Anyway, you can have a look to `purrr::map`. Here's an example with `iris` dataset: `output <- map(levels(iris$Species), function(x){
  iris |> 
    filter(str_detect(Species,x))
}
)

names(output) <- levels(iris$Species)`